# Using a js object or a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code below, which works fairly well. But I am debating if it should be an object like it is, or a plugin.

Right now it's an object in the global namespace, which is "bad" but if I did it as a plugin I am not sure what to bind it to since it doesn't really have a main element.....

It works, but it doesn't feel right.
I guess using a plugin or something in the objects functions I wouldn't have to use flashMessage. but could use this. ?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    flashMessage = {
        success: function(message, element) {
            flashMessage.showMessage('success', message, element);
        },
        error: function(message, element) {
            flashMessage.showMessage('error', message, element);
        },
        showMessage: function(type, message, element) {
            $('div.alert').remove();
            element = element ? element : '.main-content';
            var template = flashMessage.getTemplate(type);
            if(template) {
                $(element).prepend(template).find('.message').first().text(message);
            }
        },
        getTemplate: function(type) {
            return $('#' + type + '-flash-template').html();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for plugins.

You should wrap in in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (immediately invoked function expression) with the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript):

```
 var flashmessage = function(){
     var success=function(message, element){ showMessage('success', message, element); };
     var error=function(message, element){ showMessage('error', message, element);};
     // you got it, right?
     return { success:success, error:error /*and the rest*/ }
 }();
```

So you do not pollute *global namespace*; only flashmessage is visible (like in your example). But here the logic is encapsulated in a closure. It takes your object one step further.

Comment: Thanks this looks quite good. So you don't use this. you can just call the function it's self (showmessage)? since it's all wrapped in the main function?